# ASP.net serialize() form, datetime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have html form, and I submit it with ajax, but in form I have datetime (field), somehow datetime is switching places (month and day), I think that is because of serialize() function which I use to serialize data.

Is there any solution for this, I need to pass datetime every time (independently of pc date and time setting) in format yyyy/MM/dd

I'm not using [DataType(DateType.Date)], because I am using datepicker (bootstrap),  in Chrome I get 2 datepickers (in firefox just one, mine), my solution is to remove it, and it works fine (ordinary form submit)

Comment: you need to explicitly state what format you want to use when serializing.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `.serialize()` What value are you sending and what is the culture on your server?

Comment: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
, I'm sending datetime data, it works perfecty with "ordinary form" but when I submit over ajax it switch places

Comment: Are you also using `[DataType(DateType.Date)]` to render the browsers HTML5 datepicker? (You need to edit your question to include all the relevant details)

Comment: Topic edit done :)

Comment: update : This only happens in Chrome, in Firefox it works ok.